# hadoop Task Side-Effect Files

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm using hadoop with 0 Reduces. The goal is to create an object incrementally in the `map` method. Then at some point write (serialize) it to the output folder. Like I said the `reduce` piece won't do anything here. How do I do this? This is what I have:

In the configure method I get the path to the file:

```
@Override
public void configure(JobConf conf) {      
  taskSideEffectFile = FileOutputFormat.getWorkOutputPath(conf) + "/temp";    
}
```

In the map method I'm building my object and eventually I would like to serialize it, for now I'm trying to write it always on the map method:

```
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
    OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
    throws IOException {        

  AddInstanceToClassifier(value.toString());

  try
  {             
    //serialize classifier
    weka.core.SerializationHelper.write( taskSideEffectFile, nb);

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    System.err.println("Failed to serialize classifier: " + ex.getMessage());
    throw new IOException("taskSideEffectFile: " + ex.getMessage());

  } 

}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
12/05/09 22:47:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/05/09 22:47:08 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201205091117_0015_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: taskSideEffectFile: hdfs:/192.168.78.129:9000/user/hadoop-user/output/_temporary/_attempt_201205091117_0015_m_000001_0/temp (No such file or directory)
    at naive.bayes.hadoop.MusicClassifierMapper.SaveClassifier(MusicClassifierMapper.java:168)
    at naive.bayes.hadoop.MusicClassifierMapper.map(MusicClassifierMapper.java:121)
    at naive.bayes.hadoop.MusicClassifierMapper.map(MusicClassifierMapper.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$Child.main(TaskTracker.java:2209)
```

**Note**:I'm using yahoo's hadoop-0.18.0 (I saw this as my only way to run the apps from eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is supposed to store your temp files and then "promote" them to the output folder when the task succeeds.

## Here's how you fix it

- Don't use the temp path anymore.
- So now write code to put it on a folder in HDFS that you created